# "if" conditions not working as expected

Tags: linux, perl, if-statement

I am seeing two issues with my Perl script:

- My `if` condition that has `==`,  `.`, `!=` etc. is failing
- The `ps -p $pid -o etime=` throws an error `sh: line 1: -o: command not found`

I am trying to check whether a process is already running, and if so

- If it has been running for more than 40 minutes then kill the process
- If it has been running for 30-40 minutes then issue a notification
- If it has been running for less than 30 minutes then exit

A simple `if` test fails too. I have attached example code at the end.

Could some one please let me know the cause of these issues?

```
if ( `ps -ef | grep example | grep -v grep` ) {

    print "Process is already running\n";

    my $pid = `ps -ef | grep example | grep -v grep | awk '{print \$2}'`;

    if ( `ps -p $pid -o etime= | sed -e "s/:/\\n/g" | wc -l | grep 3` ) {

        print "1. Running for more than 40 mins\n";
        `ps -ef | grep example | grep -v grep | awk '{print \$2}' | xargs kill -9`;
    }
    elsif ( `ps -p $pid -o etime= | sed -e "s/:/\\n/g" | wc -l|grep "2"` ) {

        my $pmin = `ps -p $pid -o etime= | awk -F: '{print \$1}'`;

        if ( $pmin < 30 ) {

            print "Process running for 15 mins. Exiting";
            exit;
        }
        elsif ( $pid >= 40 ) {

            print "2.Running for more than 40 mins\n";
            `ps -ef | grep example | grep -v grep | awk '{print \$2}' | xargs kill -9`;
        }
        else {

            print "Process running for 30 mins. Notify";
        }
    }
}

my $psc = `ps -ef | grep example | grep -v grep >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "Yes" || echo "No"`; 
print "PSC - $psc"; 

if ( $psc eq "Yes" ) { 
    print "running"; 
} 
else { 
    print "not running"; 
}
```

## ./test.pl

```
PSC - Yes 
not running
```

Comment: An `if` is not a loop construct. It's a control flow structure.

Comment: You're using multiple copies of `ps`, `sed`, `grep`, `awk`, `echo`, `wc`, `xargs` etc. when Perl is quite capable of doing the whole thing. It's a very ugly and wasteful approach, and I strongly recommend that you train yourself out of it.

Comment: `sh: line 1: -o: command not found` is because `$pid` has a newline at the end.

Comment: This fixed the issue. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below change

ps -A | grep firefox >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "Yes" || echo "No"

Answer (score 4):

I think this might be the root of your problem:

```
elsif ($pid >= 40) {
```

Because that's the process ID. Not `$pmin`. So you're basically killing and process ID >40, which will be almost any process, apart from occasionally if it randomly gets a low pid.

But pretty fundamentally - shelling out to `ps` and `grep` is painful. Replacing `:` with `\n` and then counting lines is a bit of a nasty thing to do - and then using `grep` to match a string is also pretty dirty.

Why not rewrite using something like `Proc::ProcessTable` instead?

Here's an example of how you'd read the process table, find a particular process id (or set of) and then query the time:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Proc::ProcessTable;
use Data::Dumper;

my $ps = Proc::ProcessTable->new;

my @target_processes = grep { $_->pid eq $$ } @{ $ps->table };

print Dumper \@target_processes;

sleep 10;

while (1) {

   foreach my $process ( grep { $_->cmndline =~ m/perl/ } @{ $ps->table } ) {
      sleep 5;
      print $process ->cmndline, " has been running for ",
        $process->time / 10000, "s\n";
      print Dumper \$process;
   }

}
```

Note - the `time` is a high res time

Comment: I am pretty new to Perl. Would you be able to provide a link or referral on how to use the Proc::ProcessTable? Also, sorry about the typo I have used $pmin in my actual script. So basically if I use any if conditions my script fails. I even tried a simple if to print yes/no that does not work either.

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Edit your original post if you've further to add.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have added it to my original post now.

Comment: @Malavika: I suspect you're running your Perl code using a shell like `sh`. You need to either put a shebang line at the top or run it with `perl.exe program.pl`.